# Define DIV width in CSS so as to allow scroll/swipe in iPad2

Tags: css, ipad, width, swipe

Apologies in advance for the rudimentary nature of this CSS question.

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with widths in CSS. I have an absolute positioned `<div>` containing a fairly wide table. The `<div>` is "1300px" in width. Everything works fine on desktop browsers. People with high resolution monitors see the entire table. Those with low resolution, or those who are viewing the page from a smaller browser window, are able to horizontally scroll the div to see the entire content. All is good.

But something different happens on the iPad2 (Safari) which has a native resolution of 1024px. I expected the iPad to show the first 1024px of content and allow the user to horizontally scroll (swipe?) to see the remainder of the table. Instead, it seems to be trying to cram the entire 1300px into the 1024px screen and then shrinking the type to make everything fit.

What's the standard way of using CSS to tell the iPad browser to show whatever it can at it's native resolution (i.e. 1024) and then allow the user to swipe/scroll horizontally if he wants to see the rest? A small snippet of code would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: try <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1" /> might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default iOS Safari will scale down any page to fit the screen. If it's not your desired behavior you can instruct the browser via `meta viewport` tag in the `<head>`.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Edit: more in-depth explanation: http://www.allenpike.com/2010/choosing-a-viewport-for-ipad-sites/

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an iPad so I can't see, but a few points:

Your xhtml is not valid. `<center>` doesn't exist anymore (and by the looks of things isn't actually needed in the design anyway), also you should specify the dimensions of any the header image in px.

Don't know why you're using `margin:auto` on anything other than the `mainwrap`. Try `margin:0;` instead.

Try adding `* {margin:0; padding:0}` to the top of your stylesheet, and then adding in any extra padding and margin you need later - this will more or less set all browsers to the same starting point when it comes to layout.

If you don't want a border use `{border:none}` (if you say `border: 0px solid;` some browsers will still try and draw something)

This might not fix the problem, but it will be step in the right direction as the more valid your markup is the easier browsers find it to render.

Try removing `width:100%` from any of the parent element, then try to fix it.

Hope that it works for you.

Comment: Thank you. I'll play around with the layout using some of your suggestions and see how it goes.